# how to get wishlist id from Url Magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi i am using magento enterprise, i am working in wishlist page my url is

> http://myweburl/en/wishlist/index/share/wishlist_id/6/

how can i get wishlist id from url right now i am trying to get id like this

```
$wishlistId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('wishlist_id');
```

but its giving me

> NULL

why its giving me null instead of giving me **6**

Comment: what is in `var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams())`?

Comment: i am calling this from controller through ajax

Comment: nothing empty array

Comment: what is your ajax code?

Comment: thanks for your response found solution it was a mistake in my ajax..